# How to limit the same answer within one submission of google form?

Tags: google-forms

I have created a  group project signup form using google form. And there are two blanks where the students have to fill the names of their team members, I have created dropdown lists including all students in the class. But I do not want the student to submit the response with the same name for all team members. Is there any way to restrict the student not to fill the same name? Or is there any way to prevent the students to submit the forms if they try to submit the response with invalid answers?

To make it short, what I want is:

**within one response, no same answers are allowed for different questions.**

I have tried to search online, but all of them are about how to disallow students to submit duplicate responses.

Thank you.

Comment: you should use multiple choice instead of two drop downs

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description you your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @lukaszberwid: There are some reasons that I have to use these approaches. One of them is that to have all the students' names on it will make the form look too dense.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make check boxes with the names of every student in the class. Then all they have to do is select which people are in their group.

Example:

(#) represents the check box.

(#) Student name 1
(#) Student name 2
(#) Student name 3
(#) Student name 4
(#) Student name 5
and so on.....

Then whatever boxes they check off are the ones that are in their group. Because with the check boxes, they can't pick the same person twice. That's because it is only one question, but the student can pick multiple people.

I hope this answers your question, and have a wonderful rest of your day.